# How to get specific cell content in wxListCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets

As the title said, can anyone give me a simple example how to get a specific cell's content in wxListCtrl.

For example, I build a wxListCtrl list, there may be 3 columns. When I Right click or Double click on one row, then it should popup a message box to give me the content in third column of this selected row?

Answer (score 2):

Use [wxListCtrl::GetItemText()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html#ab0a596e1ad4714b6d5ee7b3180c59680) to retrieve the contents of a cell.